NextJs Webpack - Import another NextJs project B as a module/framework inside NextJs project A
I have created a NextJs project B as an independent module/framework which will have components/gui and css/scss files bundled as bundle.js using Webpack.
Installing the above inside NextJs project A the expectation is for Projects A's common css styles to override project B's css styles, if not use default project B css styles.
What I have achieved so far is creating bundle with project B. However, I am having 2 issues
Q1) How to import project B's components inside project A ?
Q2) I am getting this warning in the build logs?
This is my webpack.development.config.js and I am invoking this via package.json using:
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.development.config.js --stats detailed",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },

webpack.development.config.js:
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve('./dist'),
  },
  mode: 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx' ],
  },
  module: {

        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  publicPath: (resourcePath, context) => {
                    return path.relative(path.dirname(resourcePath), context) + "/";
                  },
                },
                options: {
                  esModule: true,
                  modules: {
                    namedExport: true,
                    localIdentName: "[name]__[contenthash]__[local]",
                  },
                  importLoaders: 1,
                },
              },
            ],
            include: /\.module\.css$/,
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader',
            ],
            exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
          },
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
              MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  publicPath: (resourcePath, context) => {
                    return path.relative(path.dirname(resourcePath), context) + "/";
                  },
                },
                options: {
                  esModule: true,
                  modules: {
                    namedExport: true,
                    localIdentName: "[name]__[contenthash]__[local]",    
                  },
                  importLoaders: 1,
                },
              },
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            include: /\.module\.scss$/,
          },
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
              MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'
            ],
            exclude: /\.module\.scss$/,
          },
          {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: [ '@babel/env' ],
              }
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.tsx$/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: [ '@babel/env', '@babel/typescript', '@babel/preset-react' ],
              }
            }
          },
        ],

  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
    }),
  ],
}



Answering the question from above, (next js build tool works directly out of the box without an external build tool) creating a separate webpack configuration file, instead modify the existing next.config.mjs in the project A or the project where you want to install the project B as a dependency. I am using Next.JS version 14.2.12.
Here, is the script for next.config.mjs:
import path from 'path';
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin';

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = ({
  
  webpack: (config) => {
    // Add custom loader for .tsx files
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.tsx?$/, // For .ts and .tsx files
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['next/babel'], // Use Next.js Babel preset
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    // Add custom loader for .scss files
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            publicPath: (resourcePath, context) => {
              return path.relative(path.dirname(resourcePath), context) + "/";
            },
          },
          options: {
            
            modules: {
              namedExport: false,
              localIdentName: "[name]__[contenthash]__[local]",
            },
            importLoaders: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
      include: /\.module\.css$/,
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader',
      ],
      exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            publicPath: (resourcePath, context) => {
              return path.relative(path.dirname(resourcePath), context) + "/";
            },
          },
          options: {
            
            modules: {
              namedExport: false,
              localIdentName: "[name]__[contenthash]__[local]",    
            },
            importLoaders: 1,
          },
        },
        'sass-loader'
      ],
      include: /\.module\.scss$/,
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'
        ],
        exclude: /\.module\.scss$/,
    });

    // Add MiniCssExtractPlugin to the Webpack plugins array
    config.plugins.push(
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash].css',
        chunkFilename: 'static/css/[id].[contenthash].css',
      })
    );

    return config;
  },
});

export default nextConfig;

inside project B just run the default npm run build without any configurations, push it on npm and install it in project A.
